# Can you break this pythonic list comprehension down

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I encountered this List Comprehension when looking for interesting ways to solve longest increasing subsequence problems:

```
def lis(a):
    L = []
    for (k,v) in enumerate(a):
        L.append(max([L[i] for (i,n) in enumerate(a[:k]) if n<v] or [[]], key=len) + [v])
    return max(L, key=len)
```

I've tried to understand it, but this is the best way I could understand it:

```
def lis(a):
    L = []
    for (k,v) in enumerate(a):
        for (i,n) in enumerate(a[:k]):
            if n < v:
                L.append(max(L[i]) + [v])
            else:
                L.append([[]])
        #L.append(max([L[i] for (i,n) in enumerate(a[:k]) if n<v] or [[]], key=len) + [v])
    return max(L, key=len)
```

But this is incorrect... any help? Thank you.

Edit:

New code:

```
def lis(a):
    L = []
    for (k,v) in enumerate(a):
        for (i,n) in enumerate(a[:k]):
            if n < v:
                L.append(max(L[i], key=len) + [v])
            else:
                L.append([[]] + [v])
```

When I run this on this list:

```
a = [5, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 10, 2, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5]
```

I get this error:

```
  L.append(max(L[i], key=len) + [v])
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `+ [v]` in the else statement.

Edit (think it's right):

```
def lis(a):
    L = []
    for (k, v) in enumerate(a):
        tmp = []
        for (i, n) in enumerate(a[:k]):
            if n < v:
                tmp.append(L[i])
        if len(tmp) == 0:
            tmp = [[]]
        L.append(max(tmp, key=len) + [v])
    return max(L, key=len)
```

Comment: Okay, let's say I do add that. I get this error:

in lis
    L.append(max(L[i], key=len) + [v])
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()